# How to derive desired sequence from a string using standard java api?

Tags: java

I need to get parts of a string in a particular format. Tried
everything from split, substring to pattern and matcher. but everytime
it fails with one of the requirements.

Suppose

```
str = (((abc) shdj (def) iueexs (ghi)) mkek ONE(tree23) bjm
(twooo(bug OR bag)) mvnj THR-EE(<*>$##))
```

And terms wanted are :

```
"Hard Coded Term1":abc
"Hard Coded Term2":def
"Hard Coded Term3":ghi
ONE:tree23
twooo:bug,bag
THR-EE:<*>$##
```

Provision to hard code the terms as in the case of first three.
Help!Help!

Comment: I can't tell what the "particular format" you're looking for is. I don't see a pattern in your desired output. Can you edit your question to clarify which terms should be picked out?

Answer (score 1):

You're in the neighborhood of doing language parsing.  Just looking at it, it looks doable with a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), but with that one short example it's hard to tell for sure.

The tricky think looks to be distinguishing `shdj (def)` which should resuit in a "hard coded term 'def'" from `ONE(tree23)` which should return "ONE:tree23".

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, you need to first properly specify your requirements, preferably in BNF or equivalent. With that out of the way, you can find the hard coded terms via a regexp `(^|[( ])[(]([^ )])[)]` (use the 2nd group), and the other terms with a regexp like `([0-9a-zA-Z-_])[(]([^ )])[)]` (use 1st group as name, 2nd group as value, but you will need to process further the 2nd group to split on operands).